# Show $\Bbb{A}^1$ is not isomorphic to any proper subset of itself.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

We work in an algebraically closed field $k$. Let $B$ a proper subset of $\Bbb{A}^1$. Apparently we get the result by comparing the coordinate rings of the two sets, and showing they’re not isomorphic as $k$-algebras. But here’s my questions:

1. I only know the definition of coordinate ring in the case if an affine algebraic set. Apparently we can define the coordinate ring of $B$ as the ring $k[X]/I(B)$, even if $B$ is not an affine algebraic set?
2. Supposedly, the two coordinate rings are not isomorphic, but we have $I(\Bbb{A}^1)={0}$, and if we take $B=\Bbb{A}^1-{0}$, we have $I(B)={0}$, and the two rings are isomorphic.

Comment: Isomorphic in which category?

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to solve this problem without coordinate rings. If $B$ is a proper subset of $\mathbb A^1$, then it follows from the Fundamental theorem of algebra that there are no nonconstant regular (i.e. polynomial) functions from $\mathbb A^1$ to $B$. And certainly, there are no isomorphism.

Comment: I see. Does this approach still work if we replace $0$ by an arbitrary point $p$?

Comment: Yes, it works for any proper subset of affine line.

Comment: I don't understand this solution. Could you please elaborate with details?

Comment: @JDZ: if $B$ is a proper subset of affine line then there is some $a\in k$ which doesn't lie in $B$. But by the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra the equation $f(x)=a$ has a solution.