# The 1-affine space is not isomorphic to the 1-affine space minus one point

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties, polynomial-rings

I have to prove that $\Bbb{A}^1$ is not isomorphic to $\Bbb{A}^1-\{0\}$ . Apparently one does this by showing that the corresponding coordinate rings are not isomorphic, but I have $I(\Bbb{A}^1-\{0\})= I(\Bbb{A}^1)=\{0\}$, so I get that the coordinate rings are isomorphic...

Comment: Both your varieties are affine and for an affine variety $X$ the co-ordinate ring has the property $X=\mathrm{Spec}\, A$, where $A$ is the coordinate ring. So, two affine varieties are not isomorphic if and only if their co-ordinate rings not isomorphic.

Comment: It seems like you're trying to compute the coordinate ring of $\mathbb{A}^1-\{0\}$ as a quotient $k[X]/I$ for some ideal $I$. But $\mathbb{A}^1-\{0\}$ is not a closed subvariety of $\mathbb{A}^1$! You need to take a step back and consider what are regular functions on $\mathbb{A}^1-\{0\}$.

Comment: Would it suffice to show that the two rings of regular functions are not isomorphic? Since $\Bbb{A}^1$ is a variety, its ring of regular functions is isomorphic to its coordinate ring. But what is the definition of coordinate ring when the set is not an algebraic set (as in the case of $\Bbb{A}^1-\{0\}$?)

Comment: The question is a special case of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2619060/show-bbba1-is-not-isomorphic-to-any-proper-subset-of-itself/2620414#2620414), see my answer there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is the following:

Show first that $\mathbb A^1-\{0\}\cong V:=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb A^2:xy=1\}$ where the isomorphism is given by  $x\mapsto(x,\frac 1x)$ with inverse $(x,y)\mapsto x$. Now $V$ is an irreducible algebraic set with coordinate ring $k[x,y]/(xy-1)$ which is not isomorphic to $k[x]$ as k-algebra (look at the units!). Hence $\mathbb A^1$ is not isomorphic to $V$ and so not isomorphic to $\mathbb A^1-\{0\}$.